# Saving 'Ł' and 'ł' characters as ascii/ansi file with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, ascii, polish

I'm having hard time saving some polish characters like 'Ł' to a ascii file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync('ascii.txt','Ł','ascii');
```

I would like the output file to show 'Ł' character.
I tried buffers etc no luck.
Can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Those characters do not exist in ASCII. [See for yourself.](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Is there some reason why it has to be specifically an ASCII file? Are you sure you know what the word means?

Comment: I need to import it as ascii file to an external program, I would like it to contain those characters.

Comment: [Here](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) is a nice reading on the topic if you are interested

Comment: (Don't say ASCII unless you mean it.) While one of the ANSI encodings might work, such as Windows-1250, UTF-8 is much preferred for files and streams unless your external program won't read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible.

Neither characters are part of the [ASCII standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

To save such characters to a file, you need to encode the file with a different encoding, such as [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Answer (score 1):

ASCII does not have polish characters. See here:
[ASCII TABLE](http://www.asciitable.com/)